# I had created js (angular js code) file, but this js file not allowing to work other javascript components

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had created js (angular js code) file like below, but this js file not allowing to work other Javascript components.

```
'use strict';

// declare modules
angular.module('Authentication', []);
angular.module('Home', []);

angular.module('BasicHttpAuthExample', [
    'Authentication',
    'Home',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies'
])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/authentication/views/login.html',
            hideMenus: true
        })

        .when('/home', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/home.html'
        })
         .when('/component1', {
            controller: 'ComponentsController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/components/component1.html'
        })
        .when('/databaseconfig',{
            controller: 'DatabaseConfigController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/view/components/databaseConfig.html'
        })     

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}])
```

When (`'/component1', { controller: 'ComponentsController', templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/components/component1.html' }`) 
let us say in component1.html file, I am using `ng-show/ng-hide` is not working. If I use jquery components like `hide/show` the div based on the radio button is not working. When I am not importing above mentioned js file in component1.html then jquery (hide/show div based on radio button) angularjs (ng-show/ng-hide) components are working.

```
.run(['$rootScope','$location','$cookieStore','$http',
    function ($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
        }

        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            // redirect to login page if not logged in
            if ($location.path() !== '/login' && !$rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: can you explain what "not allowing to work other javascript components." means ?

Comment: update example to see the problem